# find number of operations in program code(sorting algorithm) depending on n

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, algorithms

For one of the exercises I need to find the amount of operations a piece of code has. The code is a sorting algorithm.

The description of this exercise is as following:

> Supposing that each operation (assignment, arithmetical, comparison etc.) is of
>   weight one, find an exact number of operations L(n). Number of operations should
>   be counted for the worst case of initial data (maximum taken on all possible data of
>   size n).

The program code is show beneath this line.

```
1. i := 1 
2. m := n - 1
3. while i < n do
4.    for j := m step -1 to i do
5.       if A[j] > A[j + 1] then
6.          key := A[j + 1]
7.          A[j + 1] := A[j]
8.          A[j] := key
9.    i := i + 1
```

Based on this code I looked for the amount of number of operations it will take to complete the code based on n. This resulted in the following:
1. has $1$ operation
2. has $1$ operation
3. has $n$ operations
4. has $2\sum n-i+1$ operations
 
5. has $2\sum n-i$ operations
6. has $2\sum n-i$ operations
7. has $2\sum n-i$ operations
8. has $\sum n-i$ operations
9. has $n-1$ operations

so in total the formula of this piece of code is:
$$2+n+2\sum(n-i+1)+7\sum(n-i)+n-1$$

I know that $S = (n-1)+(n-2)(n-3)+...+1$

because of the above I can conclude that $\sum _{i=2}^n\left(\:i\:\right)$

So the formula for this piece of code is now:

$2+n+2\sum _{i=2}^n\left(\:i+1\:\right)+7\sum _{i=2}^n\left(\:i\:\right)+n-1$

if I calculate the sums inside of this formula i get the following:
$2+n+2(\frac{n^2+3n}{2}-2)+7(\frac{n^2+3n}{2}-1))+n-1$
simplified:
$n^2+5n+\frac{\left(7\left(n^2=3n\right)\right)}{2}\:-10$

this looks in my opinion good. However, if I try to compare the results of numbers of operations of this formula and doing it by hand it isn't right. With my comparison i used $n = 2$ and the number were $A={6,3}$. So this is the worst case scenario for 2 numbers. I got the following answers:

- The formula gives a way to high number: 39
- Doing it by hand gives: 15.

So somewhere i miscalculated something.

Currently I m starting to think that this part is done wrong:

> I know that $S = (n-1)+(n-2)(n-3)+...+1$
>   because of the above I can conclude that $\sum _{i=2}^n\left(\:i\:\right)$

I m thinking this because this is the correct answer if the formula goes like:
$S = 1+2+...+(n-1)+n$. I skip the first one so 1 is not included.

however my formula goes like this:
$S = n+ (n-1)+(n-2)(n-3)+...+1$. The first one is skipped so n is not included.